# Deleted dll file in error

Tags: file-management

I deleted a licensed application, an sh10.dll file, a $200 program, by mistake and I can't get it back, I can't locate it at all. Resetting to prior date did not work. I called the company and they want to charge me again! I have Windows XP, an older version.  Help!

Comment: The "licensed application" you refer to is [Shorthand](http://www.pcshorthand.com/index.html), correct? If the DLL file isn't in the Recycle Bin, and you don't have a system image from before you deleted the file, then there isn't any way to recover the application without the company's assistance.

Comment: Yes it was called Speedtype!  Thanks so much for helping me  :(.   I actually just retired so I can live without it I guess!

Comment: You could always use something like RECUVA